# Checking whether some text consists only of some pattern

Tags: python, regex, matching

I have the following problem: I'm trying to check whether some text consists only of a number of repetitions of some pattern. I.e I have a 1000 lines text and want to check if it consists only of

```
asd
123
```

I tried matching not the pattern, but `(pattern)+` hoping that it will match whatever there is to match but it was to no avail. My other idea was to split the string with the text upon the regex, but it didn't work either. I'm writing this using python re module if it matters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try matching the string with `^(?:asd|123)+$`, if it matches, then it only contains combinations of `asd` or `123` (at least one).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant: `^(abc|123)+$`

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a function in the re module that would make it match greedy instead of adding ^ and $. :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this in Python, but the regex for what you are asking for would be the following:

```
.asd$
.123$
```

Try reading through the following webpage and see if it gives you a better understanding:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Hope this helps!